# How do I change name format in TSQL Query Result?

Tags: t-sql

I have a simple tsql select query that returns a user's name in this format: 
e.g. Doe, John

How do I update the output so that it is in the format John Doe?

I have tried using a split string function but it returns multiple rows rather than 2 columns... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string

Comment: What is this 'simple tsql select query' that you speak of? Help us to help you...

Comment: I realise you may not be able to change the DB design but for completeness I'm compelled to say it is usually better to store first and last names separately and format them in the UI for this precise reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(100) = 'Doe, Jane'


SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name,CHARINDEX(',',@Name)+1,LEN(@Name) - CHARINDEX(',',@Name) )+ ' ' + SUBSTRING(@Name,1,CHARINDEX(',',@Name)-1)
```